# adding new pages only if needed to pdf at runtime using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf, migradoc

I have some problems adding new pages. I want to add new pages only if needed and measured by
the XParagraph (text) length. If the length doesnt fit on one page, a new page must be added.
Also the header and footer need to be added to every new page.
It is probably easy to solve if I know how to do that, but I dont.

I am using Migradoc Dll for generating pdf at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Invoice-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: like this but i need to extend the page